# pyautogui search for photo many times in photo

Tags: python, pyautogui

Although the searched "aaa.png" photo is found more than once in the screenshot, it only finds 1. I want it to find all of them. What can I do for it

```
iml = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(158, 284, 628, 679))
while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('aaa.png', confidence=0.9, grayscale=True) != None:
        for a in pyautogui.locateOnScreen('aaa.png'):
            print(a)
```

output:

```
407
302
81
85
...
```

screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHDB6.png

aaa.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dow8f.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `locateAllOnScreen` to find all instances.

```
for pos in pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('someButton.png')
   print(pos)
```

[Update re comment]

I can't use the 'screenshot' function but this program:

```
import pyautogui
res = pyautogui.locateAll('Dow8f.png', 'aHDB6.png',confidence=0.95, grayscale=True)
for a in res:
    print(a)
```

Gave me 25 hits, e.g:

```
Box(left=9, top=584, width=81, height=85)
Box(left=115, top=584, width=81, height=85)
Box(left=222, top=584, width=81, height=85)
Box(left=541, top=584, width=81, height=85)
```

[You don't say which version of pyautogui you are using; the latest version will NOT return 'None' if there are no matches from `locateOnScreen`, so maybe you have an old version?]

[This issue](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/207) in the pyautogui Github might be relevant. The default `confidence` level might be too finicky, so use a value as I showed above.]

Comment: still keep returning the same answer Box(left=407, top=302, width=81, height=85)...